# moodle not working properly after installation

Tags: apache, moodle

I have installed moodle many times. But this time when i install moodle all steps are completed uptil update profile. (localhost/moodle/user/editadvanced.php id=2) when i enter admin details and update file nothing is displayed. when i try to access moodle module through localhost chrome displays message "web page has a redirect loop".
localhost/moodle/admin/index.php page is not redirected. i have reinstalled Xampp. 
in Apache error log i found following

> RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an
>   ID which matches the server name

.
i found solution some where to comment include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf but it another error is activated in error log

> "Sessioncache is not configured"

. Also i have changed port 443 but it didn't work

Answer (score 10):

Find the moodledata folder.
Inside the moodledata 
there are many folders

1. Delete all from Cache

2.Delete all from Session

Restart your browser.

It worked for me.
Hope that works for you.

Comment: Worked for me also on Windows 10 for Moodle 3.1. thanks

Comment: I already deleted all the files from cache and session. I even restarted my browser but it's still not working on my side :(

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reply. I have found another solution.
While i was accessing a service provided by Linux server i got message that service has been blocked by security settings. I searched and while searching for that problem i found the solution of both.

> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/DYk8tSV8qM4

go to control panel, programs, click on java, security.
set security to medium.

Java security was set to high which was blocking moodle application.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the cache and the sesson folder data's in the moodle data folder. It will prevent you from redirecting the loop.
It is worked for me.But deleting the whole moodledata folder is not recommended

Comment: Yes, don't delete the entire `/moodledata` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess... but if you are using a certificate, have you tried using https in your config.php?

```
$CFG->wwwroot = 'https://...'
```